# If you create a mirror of a git repository and delete the original do you lose the original contributions as well?

Tags: github

If you create a mirror of a git repository and delete the original do you lose the original contributions as well?

Comment: Wwhat do you mean by mirror? Fork?

Answer (score 0):

If those contributions were merged to the original repo that you just [forked](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) or [duplicated (`clone --mirror`/`push --mirror`)](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/), then no: you get the full history.

What you would be losing would be the [PR (Pull Requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/), and their associated comments) and the issues. As well as the [wiki, if you did not cloned it](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/).